# Inserting a column with values by searching within the same dataframe, and applying conditional statements, in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I want to create a *dataframe*, named **POI_gps**:

- Id(numeric)
- lat (numeric)
- long (numeric)
- Timestamp (POSIXct)
- 3min (POSIXct) (to be done by adding 60*3 to Timestamp)
- isStay (True/False) (looking to create a boolean field)

There are about 100,000 observations inside the dataframe.

Sample of location_gps

| Timestamp | id | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-06 06:28:01 | 35 | 36.0762 | 24.8747 |
| 2014-01-06 06:28:01 | 35 | 36.0762 | 24.8746 |
| 2014-01-06 06:28:03 | 1 | 36.0661 | 24.8826 |

```
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1388960881, 1388960881, 1388960883, 1388960885, 1388960886, 1388960887), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), id = c(35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35), lat = c(36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762), long = c(24.8747, 24.8746, 24.8744, 24.8743, 24.8742, 24.8741)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My idea is to check whether the same vehicle is at the same lat/long after 3mins. If it is, isStay would be TRUE, if it is not, isStay would be FALSE.

I have written a function for this:

```
searchGPS <- function(gpsTime, vehID, current.lat, current.long){
  x <- POI_gps %>%
    filter(id == vehID &
             Timestamp == (gpsTime + 60*3))
  
  ifelse(dim(x), return(FALSE),
         ifelse((x$lat[1] == current.lat & x$long[1] == current.long), return(TRUE), return(FALSE)))
  
}
```

I tried doing this but it doesn't work. I am new to R.

```
POI_gps <- locations_gps %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate("3min" = Timestamp + 60*3) %>%
  mutate("stay" = searchGPS("3min", id, lat, long))
```

This is my error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `stay`.
I `stay = searchGPS("3min", id, lat, long)`.
x Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
I Input `..1` is `id == vehID & Timestamp == (gpsTime + 60 * 5)`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
I The error occurred in group 1: id = 1.
I The error occurred in group 1: id = 1.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data using `dput(head(location_gps))`

Comment: structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1388960881, 1388960881, 
1388960883, 1388960885, 1388960886, 1388960887), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), id = c(35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35), lat = c(36.0762, 
36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762), long = c(24.8747, 
24.8746, 24.8744, 24.8743, 24.8742, 24.8741)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

sorry, does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are attempting to do correctly, you can just do:

```
locations_gps |>
  mutate(min3 = Timestamp + 180) |> 
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(stay = if_else(min3 <= lag(min3) & lat == lag(lat) & long == lag(long), TRUE, FALSE)) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Timestamp              id   lat  long min3                stay 
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <lgl>
1 2014-01-05 14:28:01    35  36.1  24.9 2014-01-05 14:31:01 NA   
2 2014-01-05 14:28:01    35  36.1  24.9 2014-01-05 14:31:01 FALSE
3 2014-01-05 14:28:03    35  36.1  24.9 2014-01-05 14:31:03 FALSE
4 2014-01-05 14:28:05    35  36.1  24.9 2014-01-05 14:31:05 FALSE
5 2014-01-05 14:28:06    35  36.1  24.9 2014-01-05 14:31:06 FALSE
6 2014-01-05 14:28:07    35  36.1  24.9 2014-01-05 14:31:07 FALSE
```

Note that variable names cannot start with a number.

Comment: Oh my goodness, you solved it for me. That is exactly what I wanted. If their location is the same as of 3 mins later, stay will be TRUE. And your codes are so elegant and neat!

Thank you so much! Sorry that I couldn't upvote your answer because I do not have enough reputation. But thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, you should be able to accept it using the checkmark icon and consider your problem solved though.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!

Comment: If I may, is there any way I could adjust the conditions such that it does not look at exactly 3 mins later but 3 mins (+- 30s), choosing the lat/long closest to the 3mins mark? Because I realised, due to the unpredictable nature of the GPS, it does not record the data every seconds. It could skip a second and go to the next, or even 10-30s later.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter to change the integer to add to Timestamp from 180 to whatever you wish? The current logic is that any time differences that is less than 3 minutes would be counted.

Comment: And that it will take the result nearest to 3 mins? I am asking this because when I tried to plot it across 100,000 observations, a significant number of lat/long appeared and I used distinct(lat,long) to find the number of locations it detected. It was a good number and all is good.

However, when I tried to plot the locations in groups, differentiated by id, the numbers of locations are very few. It is like 2 or 3 locations within 2 weeks, which doesn't make sense.

My suspicion is that the immediate 3 min might not have a match, so I might need to find a match within the 3 min.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance and I really appreciate the help. I attempted to change the numbers, to 5 mins or even 1hrs and some ridiculous numbers, but my observations remained the same. At 3mins, it is 77 observations, 5mins also 77 observations. The same goes for all other numbers, 1hr or more. I'm not sure why it happen.

Comment: Please post a separate question. At this point I have trouble following what the issue is.